# In general, do data-structures receive more read operations or write operations?

Tags: performance, optimization, concurrency

A professor of mine made the claim that Hash Sets, in use, usually receive more reads than writes, so when designing one concurrently, you should optimize for a contains function to be the quickest.

He never gave a citation for that, so I was wondering if there were any resources that discussed anything like this.

I think it could be relevant to know **where** you should try to optimize your programs based on how they are used.

Comment: Specific to hash sets: each write also implies a read, so `contains` function optimization is essential. It is hard to make a blanket claim like that though. One common use of hash sets is deduping, and that's many writes and one read. Each write still calls `contains` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definitive answer for this, because it all depends on the application the data structure will be used for. Hash Sets are good for finding an object by key (read) quickly, and that is probably why they will be used in scenarios where they are read more than written to. Linked lists are fast when inserting, but slow to find by a key, so it wouldn't be good to use in place of a hash when the application requires that.

It would be wrong to model your logic around a chosen data structure, instead, data structures must be chosen fittingly for your logic, which may be read-heavy or write-heavy.